# Switching elements' visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm building a web app, where you can configure a bike. You can select parts, and if you click on a part, the part image will be shown, so its style will change from `none` to `block`. I wanted to use ReactJS, but I'm having a hard time understanding it. I couldn't find a better way to hide the elements I want, except of jQuery. This is what I have in my code:

```
var bikeInfo = {
    parts: [
        {
            id: 1,
            img: "http://designyourbike.ch/dyb_img/parts/154-2015071616148075.png",
            style: {
                top: 0,
                left: "432px",
                display: "none"
            }
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            img: "http://designyourbike.ch/dyb_img/parts/189-2015071616141931.png",
            style: {
                top: 0,
                left: "432px",
                display: "none"
            }
        }
    ]
}

var Nav = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var partID = e.target.getAttribute("data-part");

        $(".part").hide();
        $("#part-" + partID).show();
    },
    render: function() {
        var parts = this.props.bikeInfo.parts;

        var _this = this;

        return (
            <div className="nav">
                {
                    parts.map(function(part) {
                        return (
                            <a href="#" data-part={part.id} onClick={_this.handleClick}>{"Part " + part.id}</a>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var Bike = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    render: function() {
        var parts = this.props.bikeInfo.parts;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="parts">
                    <img src="http://designyourbike.ch/dyb_img/parts/152-201506308399268.png" />

                    {
                        parts.map(function(part) {
                            return (
                                <img className="part" style={part.style} id={"part-" + part.id} src={part.img} onClick={this.handleClick} />
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<Nav bikeInfo={bikeInfo} />, document.getElementById("nav"));
React.render(<Bike bikeInfo={bikeInfo} />, document.getElementById("bike"));
```

My question is, is there any other way (better, faster, more React-ish way) of doing this, without using jQuery at all.

Live JSFiddle of current result:

https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/12521/

Answer (score 0):

I like to add an inline-style to the element you want to hide and show to have it's CSS set by the components state.  so whatever event occurs you update the state to display: none or display: inherit.

In this way, it's not necessary to have jQuery hide and show.

Comment: If anyone's looking for an example, it might go something like this: 

var handle2Styles = {
      display: (this.state.handle2) ? 'block' : 'none'
}

Seems like the cleanest way to me too :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Part component and pass its visibility into its props or alternatively store visibility in its state. 
In Part's render method, return null if the part currently invisible or return your img tag otherwise.

In handleClick method just change visibility of the part. React will do the rest.

Something like this:

```
var Part = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        if(!this.props.visible) {
            return null;
        }
        return <img className="part" style={this.props.style} id={"part-" + this.props.id} src={this.props.src} onClick={this.handleClick} />
    }
});
var Bike = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var parts = this.props.bikeInfo.parts;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="parts">
                    <img src="http://designyourbike.ch/dyb_img/parts/152-201506308399268.png" />

                    {
                        parts.map(function(part) {
                            return (
                                <Part visible={part.visible} style={part.style} id={"part-" + part.id} src={part.img} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: This sounds promising. I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: I'm doing the `handleClick` this way, but it's not working: `this.props.bikeInfo.parts[parseInt(partID) - 1].visible = true;`. The prop is changed, but the components are not re-rendered. Here's the updated fiddle, can you please help me further?https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/12626/

Comment: The component renders when its state changed, that's why your code is not working - state remains the same. You need to implement some kind of root component that will contain and modify state and pass the state to its child components as props. I slightly modified your code, I hope you'll get the point. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/const314/69z2wepo/12632/

Answer (score 0):

I think the most "react" way would be to use state and props. In the Nav component, set a state to be the part selected. Then, in the render function, add Bike component as a child that receives the part state as a prop. Then, make the Bike component look to the props, not the bikeInfo, to display the image. I attached some code to give you an idea...

```js
var bikeInfo = {
    parts: [
        {
            id: 1,
            img: "http://designyourbike.ch/dyb_img/parts/154-2015071616148075.png",
            style: {
                top: 0,
                left: "432px",
                display: "none"
            }
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            img: "http://designyourbike.ch/dyb_img/parts/189-2015071616141931.png",
            style: {
                top: 0,
                left: "432px",
                display: "none"
            }
        }
    ]
}

var Nav = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { part: {} };
    },
    handleClick: function(part) {
        this.setState({part: part});
    },
    render: function() {
        var parts = this.props.bikeInfo.parts;
        
        var _this = this;
        
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="nav">
                    {
                        parts.map(function(part) {
                        var boundClick = _this.handleClick.bind(null, part);
                            return (
                                <a href="#" data-part={part.id} onClick={boundClick}>{"Part " + part.id}</a>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            <div id="bike">
                <Bike part={this.state.part} />
            </div>
            </div>
            
            
        )
    }
});

var Bike = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(e) { 
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="parts">
                    <img src="http://designyourbike.ch/dyb_img/parts/152-201506308399268.png" />
                    <img className="part" style={this.props.part.style} id={"part-" + this.props.part.id} src={this.props.part.img} onClick={this.handleClick} />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<Nav bikeInfo={bikeInfo} />, document.getElementById("nav"));
```

Comment: There's something wrong with this code. Can you please help me, I wasn't able to debug it.

Comment: Sorry -- there were two problems. First, I was still referencing the bikeInfo props in the Bike component even though they weren't set. Then, in the boundClick bind, it should have been null, not this.